# Flask app ImportError when running on Docker

Tags: python, docker, flask

I have a basic Flask web app that I want to set up inside a Docker container. The following is my Dockerfile setup:

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine

WORKDIR /mydir

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
ENV FLASK_APP="app.py"

CMD [ "python3", "-m" , "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0", "-p", "8080"]
```

Built the docker file with

```
mydir % docker build -t geode:latest .
```

But when I try to run the web app through Docker, this happens:

```
mydir % docker run -p 8080:8080 geode:latest
 * Serving Flask app 'app.py' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
Usage: python -m flask run [OPTIONS]
Try 'python -m flask run --help' for help.

Error: While importing 'app', an ImportError was raised.
```

However, I can run the web app locally with the following

```
mydir % python3 -m flask run --host=0.0.0.0 -p 8080
```

So I'm not sure why I'm getting an "ImportError" when I run it via docker but not when I run the command myself.

Comment: What is structure of local build directory? And what is code of `app.py`?

Comment: Local directory has `app.py` and the `Dockerfile` in the same root level. The Flask app itself has `app=Flask(__name__)`

Comment: By the way `FLASK_APP` should be an app name without `.py` extension according this [article](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/cli/#application-discovery)

Comment: Oh so like `ENV FLASK_APP=“app”`? I’ll change that, but I also got it to work as is just by rebuilding the docker container. Odds are there was a typo somewhere that I didn’t catch until after building the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why but rebuilding the Docker container allowed it to run properly... Maybe I had a typo in the Dockerfile that I changed after I built the container? Not sure, but I was copying the structure I used for another app - the original worked and this didn't. So there was a typo somewhere and rebuilding the container worked.

Answer (score 1):

Probably flask cannot find the source file from which to import the `app` variable, or a variable called `app` does not exist in the source file from which to import the variable.

Check out this [link](https://www.twilio.com/blog/how-run-flask-application) to see how to launch a flaks application.

If the name of the variable or file containing the `app` variable is different from the standard, then you can set the `FLASK_APP` environment variable inside the `Dockerfile` to tell flask where to get what it needs.

```
ENV FLASK_APP=<PATH_TO_APP.PY>:<APP_VARIABLE_NAME>
```

Comment: Rebuilding the container worked. Not sure why, maybe I had a typo in one of the files when I first built it, refreshing the container build fixed the problem.